# How can I loop through an object that has a status active/inactive and only show No Results once for inactive status without duplicate each records?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I'm stuck with a problem whereby I need to show only records that are active and hide inactive ones from a REST API call that I'm making.

If all records are inactive, just show only single message saying "No Records Found" for instance.

```js
const [tenants, setTenants] = useState([]);
const tenant_status_active = 0;
```

```
<table className="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive caption-top">
  <caption>Tenants Info:</caption>
  <thead className="table-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>Room No.:</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>E-mail Address</th>
      <th>Is Deposit Paid?</th>
      <th>Lease End Date</th>
      <th colSpan={2}>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {tenants.map(tenant => (tenant.tenantStatus !== tenant_status_active)
      ? (
        <tr>
          <td colSpan={7} className="text-danger">No Results</td>
        </tr>
      )
      : (
        <tr key={tenant.id}>
          <td>{tenant.roomNumber}</td>
          <td>{tenant.name} {tenant.surname}</td>
          <td>{tenant.email}</td>
          <td>{tenant.leaseEndDate}</td>
          <td>
            <button
              aria-label="Delete tenant"
              className="btn btn-danger" 
              onClick={() => deleteTenant(tenant)}
            >
              Delete
            </button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button
              aria-label="Update tenant"
              className="btn btn-primary" 
              onClick={() => updateTenant(tenant)}
            >
              Update
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      )) 
    }
  </tbody>
  <tfoot className="table-dark">
    <tr>
      <td colSpan={7}><small>Table Data &copy;</small></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Tried to do a lot of google search for answers, also here on Stack overflow, and asked my instructor from Udemy for help. Unfortunately nothing is forthcoming at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the inactive records and check active tenant array length:

```
const activeTenants = tenants.filter(tenant => tenant.tenantStatus === tenant_status_active);

return <table className="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive caption-top">
             <caption>Tenants Info:</caption>
                    <thead className="table-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Room No.:</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>E-mail Address</th>
                            <th>Is Deposit Paid?</th>
                            <th>Lease End Date</th>
                            <th colSpan={2}>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {
                            tenants.length === 0 ? 
                                (<tr>
                                    <td colSpan={7} className="text-danger">No Results</td>
                                </tr>)
                            :
                            tenants.map(tenant => 
                            (
                                <tr key={tenant.id}>
                                    <td>{tenant.roomNumber}</td>
                                    <td>{tenant.name} {tenant.surname}</td>
                                    <td>{tenant.email}</td>
                                    <td>{tenant.leaseEndDate}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button aria-label="Delete tenant" className="btn btn-danger" 
                                        onClick={ () => deleteTenant(tenant) }>
                                            Delete
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button aria-label="Update tenant" className="btn btn-primary" 
                                        onClick={ () => updateTenant(tenant) }>
                                            Update
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            )) 
                         }
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot className="table-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <td colSpan={7}><small>Table Data &copy;</small></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help guys, this is great for now.

Answer (score 0):

Filter the `tenants` state for the tenants that have the correct active status value, and conditionally render either the fallback UI if *that* array is empty or the mapped JSX.

Example:

```
const [tenants, setTenants] = useState([]);
const tenant_status_active = 0;

const activeTenants = React.useMemo(() => {
  return tenants.map(tenant => tenant.tenantStatus !== tenant_status_active);
}, [tenants, tenant_status_active]);

return (
  <table className="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive caption-top">
    <caption>Tenants Info:</caption>
    <thead className="table-dark">
      ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {activeTenants.length
        ? activeTenants.map(tenant => ( // <-- truthy length, map array elements
          <tr key={tenant.id}>
            <td>{tenant.roomNumber}</td>
            <td>{tenant.name} {tenant.surname}</td>
            <td>{tenant.email}</td>
            <td>{tenant.leaseEndDate}</td>
            <td>
              <button
                aria-label="Delete tenant"
                className="btn btn-danger" 
                onClick={() => deleteTenant(tenant)}
              >
                Delete
              </button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button
                aria-label="Update tenant"
                className="btn btn-primary" 
                onClick={() => updateTenant(tenant)}
              >
                Update
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))
        : ( // <-- falsey length, render fallback
          <tr>
            <td colSpan={7} className="text-danger">No Results</td>
          </tr>
        )
      }
    </tbody>
    <tfoot className="table-dark">
      ...
    </tfoot>
  </table>
);
```